# Centering shapes in HTML canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas, center

I have an HTML canvas with a rectangle like this:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.stroke();
```

Is it possible to center that rectangle in the canvas with css? I want it to stay centered regardless of what the width of the canvas is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The canvas is just a bunch of pixels. There are no elements for CSS to influence.

If you want to centre something inside the canvas, then you have to pick the right place the put the pixels you are colouring in the first place.

You might be better off using SVG for your graphics, especially if they are simple shapes like rectangles.

Comment: When you resize the canvas all content will be cleared off the canvas.  So when you're resizing the canvas you can just redraw the rectangles at a newly centered location.  Agreed about SVG. Since SVGs are actual DOM elements you can let CSS reflow them during resizing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to center the rectangle on canvas:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var width = 130, height = 80;//Dimensions of rectangle
var x = canvas.Width/2, y = canvas.Height/2;//Center coordinates of rectangle 
ctx.rect(x - width/2, y - height/2, width, height);
ctx.stroke();
```

Refer this for the [pictorial representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYQEi.png)